# Javafx, Is there a way to check state of buttons and do an if statement depending on its state?

Tags: java, javafx

In Javafx there is an option to set colors/styles for buttons e.g.,

```java
button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
```

Is there any syntax for checking a buttons style for witch color the button has?

Basically I want to do something like:

```java
if (button.style("-fx-background-color: red")) {
something....
}
```

Comment: You can certainly do this, but may I ask why? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm making a battleship game. Cheking for what color buttons has is an easy way to check which buttons has already been pressed.

Comment: Rather than using the state of the view to control the flow of the game, you should instead have a model that represents the game and the view updates to show the state of the model.

Comment: Yeah I kinda did that, since I didn't know how to check for colors :)
I made an array from 0-100 since its a 10x10 grid and choose a random number from the array.
Now I need to figure out how to place ships, how to show them propperly and how to interact with them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it via `.contains()` or via regular expression (`.matches()`) by using `getStyle()` (for example, in your case, it would be `button.getStyle().contains("-fx-background-color: red")`.

However, keep in mind that both `setStyle()` and `getStyle()` only refer to *inline styles*. Therefore, they will not include the styles that are passed via CSS selectors in attached CSS files.

Generally, using visual properties for determining semantic properties is not considered a good practice. If you have buttons that are supposed to exhibit a particular behavior, consider extending the `Button` class and adding those as proper properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = new Button();
String[] styles = button.getStyle().split(";");
for(String style : styles){
   if(style.contains("-fx-background-color")){
       String color = style.split(": ")[1]; // the color of the button
   }
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation of what you're doing here if they asked a question its because they don't understand why what their doing isn't working and not explaining what you're doing is only going to confuse them more. You can also take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)